# Extract specific text in tr beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm stuck with getting information from html code with beautifulsoup. I extracted the HTML piece below by doing the following steps:

```
result = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
tably = soup.find("table", id="table4")
last_row = tably.findAll('tr')[-1]
```

Now, I want to obtain the following output:

```
Classification: Mass murderer
Characteristics: Militant Al-Takfir wa al-Hijran (Renunciation and Exile) faction
Number of victims: 23
```

Sample HTML:

```
    <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 8pt; color: #000000" width="100%">
    <style color="#000000" face="Verdana">
                  Classification: <b>Mass murderer</b></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #000000">
                                             
                  <style="font-size: 8pt" color="#000000" face="Verdana">
                  Characteristics:&nbsp;<b>Militant Al-Takfir wa
            al-Hijran </b>(Renunciation and Exile)<b> faction</b></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #000000">
                                             
                  <style="font-size: 8pt" color="#000000" face="Verdana">
                  Number of victims:&nbsp;<b>23</b></font></td>
                </tr>
                </font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get("https://murderpedia.org/male.A/a/abbas.htm", headers=headers).text
table = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib").find("table", {"id": "table4"})

output = [
             " ".join(i.getText(strip=True).split()).split(":") for i
             in table.find_all("td") if i.getText(strip=True)
         ][:9]

print(tabulate(output))
```

Output:

```
-----------------  --------------------------------------------------------------
Classification     Mass murderer
Characteristics    Militant Al-Takfir wa al-Hijran(Renunciation and Exile)faction
Number of victims  23
Date of murders    December 8,2000
Date of birth      1967
Victims profile    Maleworshippers
Method of murder   Shooting(Kalashnikov assault rifle)
Location           Omdurman, Sudan
Status             Shot to death by police
```